# Phone doesn't boot to anything

Tags: samsung

I have my samsung galaxy a6+ (2018). I tried to install a GSI to my phone since it has a /vendor partition. First, I did OEM unlock in developer settings. It told me to reset the phone in order to do that. So I did press the reset button. As I was on stock rom, the phone turned off, and showed the blue-background android logo saying "Erasing...".

After its screen turned off again, I pressed the key combo to go to download mode. FRP and OEM UNLOCK was both off. And flashed twrp which I had compiled. The problem appeared then. After flashing, it rebooted, show the samsung logo with "Recovery is not SEANDROID enforcing, Set Warranty Bit: recovery", and screen just turned off.

Even backlight was not on. I tried multiple times to enter download mode, by pressing the key combo, but no luck. It just shows same "Recovery is not SEANDROID enforcing, Set Warranty Bit: recovery" and screen just turns off. But why? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: *"Recovery is not SEANDROID enforcing"* is a message from TWRP indicating selinux is in desired state. kernel must allow selinux permissive in order to grant TWRP root access (not enforced). *"Set Warranty Bit: recovery"* is a message from bootloader and indicates bootloader is unlocked + device has custom recovery. Both messages are just warnings and not the cause of your issue, nothing to worry about. don't trust service center (how can that warnings be displayed if mainboard wouldn't power on!?)

Comment: there is probably another reason. after OEM unlocking and factory reset it is mandatory to finish the initial setup, connect internet and confirm OEM unlock again. otherwise vaultkeeper will prevent from booting custom binaries. If that is the case, back to square one.

Comment: just realized you compiled TWRP yourself. reason could be the recovery flashed was incompatible with your device model and crashed. volume keys are recognized during aboot (which is loaded from SBL) to leave recovery mode wait a few days until battery died. make sure to press right keys when connecting charger. usb JIG dongle might also work. you should reach either SBL or EDL (one of this must come up from PBL)